# Permeability and permativity thruout all of space.

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

How do we know that the permeability and permativity of space is a constant thruout space.
The magnetic and electric components of a photon (wave) would experience higher and lower "resistance " if not constant and over a large portion of space,  and so effect the speed c.
Is it possible that this occurs (differing regions of permativity and permeability) and how could this be experimentally tested?